# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'list' and 'list'

Tags: python, dictionary, set, list-comprehension

In Python, I want to write a list comprehension to iterate over the union of the keys for 2 dictionaries. Here's a toy example:

```
A = {"bruno":1, "abe":2}.keys()
B = {"abe":5, "carlton":10}.keys()

>>>[ k for k in A | B ]
```

I'm getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-221-ed92ac3be973> in <module>()
      2 B= {"abe":5, "carlton":10}.keys()
      3 
----> 4 [ k for k in A|B]

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'list' and 'list'
```

The comprehension works just fine for 1 dictionary. For example:

```
>>>[ k for k in A]
['bruno', 'abe']
```

Not sure where the error is. I'm following an example in a textbook and according to the book, this type of union and intersection operator should work fine. Please let me know your thoughts. Thank you.

Comment: `[ k for k in set(A) | set(B) ]`

Comment: I don’t think you need to iterate over key's list.
>>> set(A+B)
set(['carlton', 'bruno', 'abe'])

Comment: @Arvind: There are far more efficient ways of doing that in Python 2. In Python 3, the posted code would work, which is where the problem lies.

Comment: @TanveerAlam: or `set(A).union(B)`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Python 2, `dict.keys()` is a list, not [dictionary view](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects). Use [`dict.viewkeys()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.viewkeys) instead:

```
A = {"bruno":1, "abe":2}.viewkeys()
B = {"abe":5, "carlton":10}.viewkeys()

[k for k in A | B]
```

Your example would have worked *in Python 3*, where the [`.keys()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects) has been changed to return a dictionary view by default.

Demo:

```
>>> A = {"bruno":1, "abe":2}.viewkeys()
>>> B = {"abe":5, "carlton":10}.viewkeys()
>>> [k for k in A | B]
['carlton', 'bruno', 'abe']
```

It sounds as if your textbook assumes you are using Python 3. Switch textbooks, or use Python 3 to run the examples, don't try to mix the two until you get a lot more experience with the differences between Python 2 and 3.

For the record, a dictionary view supports set operations with the `|`, `^`, `-` and `&` operators against any iterable on the right-hand side; so the following works too:

```
A_dict = {"bruno":1, "abe":2}
B_dict = {"abe":5, "carlton":10}

[k for k in A_dict.viewkeys() | B_dict]
```

Comment: Nice explanation!!  Though `[ k for k in set(A) | set(B) ]` this also give correct result. Is there anything wrong using it? just curious. :)

Comment: @Arvind: that'd be *far* less efficient, because you'd first create two lists from the keys, then create two sets from those again. It's the poor-mans version of what I posted, loads of extra objects being created (with extra loops in C code).

Comment: @Arvind: The dictionary views are light-weight objects that make use of the fact that dictionaries already implement most of the functionality the set operations need.

Comment: @Arvind: If you were to go that route, you'd call `set()` *directly on just one of the dictionaries* (not on the `.keys()` result), then use the `.union()` method to pass in the other dictionary, directly. That at least saves you creating too many intermediary objects. It'd still be slower.

Comment: Thanks for explanation bro. I think i need to explore more

Comment: Thank you @Martijn Pieters. I thought it had something to do with different version of Python but wasn't sure. I had no idea at all about this dictionary view. And still not sure why only one of the dictionaries need that dictionary view and the other doesn't and it still works. But oh well, I'm a beginner and am not going to delve into the nitty gritty for now. Thanks again! Very helpful.

Comment: Thank you too @Arvind for the prompt reply and suggestions.

Comment: @wubr2000: As I state at the bottom of my answer, the set operations support arbitrary iterables; so you need a set on the left-hand side, the other side only needs to support looping, really.